# Atomic operations for Dynamo DB

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-dynamodb, amazon-sqs, amazon-sns

I have two use-case :

1. I want to send a message to s3 and store it's s3 link ocation in dynamodb.
2. I want to post a message to sqs/sns and store the details in dynamodb.

In both of above cases, I have to write two steps which can breaks the atomic nature of the process. Is there a way to do any of the above operation in a single step ?

Thanks,
Anuj

Comment: You should probably look at [AWS Lambda](https://aws.amazon.com/lambda/).

Answer (score 0):

this would require distributed transaction between multiple (in this case 2) systems. You can achieve something like this by writing your own "transaction" and handling it. But there is no out of the box solution.

Be aware that with some AWS services you will be unable to "roolback" changes you made. Best example are SQS and SNS. So it whould be better for this case to first write to DynamoDB, than check if it is there if you do not belive API response (but you have to now that DynamoDB has eventual consistency) and then try to send message to SQS/SNS and if it fails delete data from DynamoDB. Also you will be unable to verify that message is in SQS (beside API response).

If you do not have any particular reason to do such transaction i would just trust AWS infrastructure, becouse you are sending small messages (link, sqs message).